# Converting XML to Map with FasterXML

Tags: java, xml, unmarshalling, fasterxml

How can I convert xml file to Map?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tree desc="container">
    <node name="node1" class="com.nodes.Node1">
        <subnodes>
            <node name="node2" class="com.nodes.Node2">
                <subnodes>
                    <node name="node3" class="com.nodes.Node3"/>
                </subnodes>
            </node>
            <node name="node4" class="com.nodes.Node4"/>
            <node name="node5" class="com.nodes.Node5">
                <subnodes>
                    <node name="node6" class="com.nodes.Node6"/>
                </subnodes>
            </node>
            <node name="node7" class="com.nodes.Node7"/>
        </subnodes>
    </node>
</tree>
```

to `Map<String, Node> treeDeps`?

Here is the Node class

```
public abstract class AbstractNode implements Node {

    String name;
    List<Node> subNodes;

    // other methods omitted
}

public interface Node {
    // methods omitted    
}
```

I don't want to create a separate entity for hold all tree. Instead of that I want to unmarshall all stuff to `Map`.

Here is my code for unmarshalling

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> val = mapper.readValue(new File(path), Map.class);
```

**UPDATE**

```
    XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
    InputStream resource = TreeReader.class.getResourceAsStream(path);
    Map<String, Object> val = mapper.readValue(resource, Map.class);
```

Now I can parse the data. But I don't need to add to my Map a `<tree>` node. So I need to exclude it. How can I do it?